# Wordpress Amazon EC2 Database Error

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, database-connection, bitnami

So, I have Bitnami Wordpress set up through a m1.small EC2 instance. About every hour, the site suddenly has a problem connecting to the database. The only way I can get it to work is by rebooting the instance.

Has anyone encountered this problem before or possibly have ideas for a fix?

Many thanks!

(Also, if you need me to provide any extra info I'd be glad to do so)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we've had this problem before with the bitnami AMI / MySQL just this week.  It's normally because the MySQL server daemon dies on the EC2 instance.

To solve, we set up the MySQL database on RDS and connected Wordpress to that instead.  The database will perform better on RDS and you won't have to worry about the daemon dying.  If RDS is not an option then you'll have to dig into the MySQL / wordpress logs to find out what's going wrong with MySQL.